# Customize output of event auditing in FreeBSD

Tags: c, unix, kernel, freebsd

I want customize output of event auditing in FreeBSD. I read the audit kernel and daemon code, and finally I found the `auditd_gen_record` function in `/usr/src/contrib/openbsm/libauditd/auditd_lib.c`, and I think this function generates event auditing records.

Since I wanted to make sure this function is function that I want, I wrote simple function and then call it in the `auditd_gen_record` function, but sample function that I wrote didn't work for some reason!

Sample function is:

```
void test_audit(void) {
    int     fd;
    int     flags   = O_WRONLY | O_APPEND;
    char *  path    = "/root/TestOutputData";
    char *  msg     = "audit gen rec\n";

    fd = open(path, flags);
    write(fd, msg, strlen(msg));
    close(fd);
}
```

If you think I'm in wrong place or function, or I should manipulate something else, please tell me. How can I manipulate FreeBSD event auditing for creating a custom logfile? Thanks!

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? Can you also show `auditd_gen_record()` for context?

Comment: I know audit_gen_record() calling, but when i add sample function, i expect that function call and then write something to TestOutputData file.
As i say, i want summerize audit log files, and if you see [auditd_gen_record()](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14541937/), you found au_close function, this function take audit descriptor and submit event, i want summerize event recorde before it submit to log files.